# How do I detect in rails if I am running a rake command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, environment

In Rails, you might want your environment to do different things on startup depending on if you are running a rake task or not. For instance, my use case was having several hundred MB of cache loaded into memory on app start. We obviously don't want this to happen on rake commands.

---update---
The following is  reliable solution and works with heroku.

```
is_rake = (ENV['RACK_ENV'].blank? || ENV['RAILS_ENV'].blank? || !("#{ENV.inspect}" =~ /worker/i).blank?)
```

Answer (score 7):

To specialcase running migrations I did the following:

```rb
if defined?(Rake) \
&& Rake.application.top_level_tasks.grep(/\Adb:migrate(\[[^\]]*\])?\z/).length > 0
  ...
end
```

Particularly, it covers the case where we're not running `rake`.

`Rake.application.top_level_tasks` is set by `rake` to the list of arguments (tasks to be executed):

https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.3/exe/rake#L27 
https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb#L81 
https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb#L97 
https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb#L751-L761

Comment: `Rails.const_defined?( "Rake" )` may be better since another module could define "Rake" for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using heroku AND you are using workers, here is a more reliable way to do this check.

```
is_rake = (ENV['RACK_ENV'].blank? || ENV['RAILS_ENV'].blank? || !("#{ENV.inspect}" =~ /worker/i).blank?)
```