# Get chain of calling rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

Let's say I have a chain of `rake` tasks

```
taskA  --(calls)-->  taskB  --(calls)-->  taskC
```

Is there any way, in the middle of `taskC` to get the list of invoking rake tasks? I.e. the chain of `rake` tasks that have been called to lead up to this task?

`caller` returns a not-so-useful stack trace in this instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a native solution, but here is what I would have done :

- Create a file named "task_chain.json"
- On the beginning of each of your tasks, append the name of the task into the Hash inside the file :

  ```
  #getting the list
  task_list = JSON.parse(File.open("task_chain.json"))

  #updating the list
  task_list << "my_new_task_name"

  #writing the list
  File.open("task_chain.json", "w"){ |file|
    file.write(JSON.pretty_generate(task_list))
  }
  ```
- Then, you just need to access this file in order to know your chain of tasks : `task_list = JSON.parse(File.open("task_chain.json"))`

You might want to make this into methods, for not repeating the same code over and over. And don't forget to empty the file before the first task of your chain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by monkey pathing Rake::Task:

```
require 'rake'

module Rake
  class Application
    #Store the chain of executions
    attr_accessor :current_task_chain
  end

  class Task
    alias_method :origin_invoke_prerequisites, :invoke_prerequisites 
    # Invoke all the prerequisites of a task.
    # Monkey patched to get list of tasks
    def invoke_prerequisites(task_args, invocation_chain) # :nodoc:
      (Rake.application.current_task_chain ||= [] ) << @name  #add the current task (prerequisite) to the "global" chain
      origin_invoke_prerequisites(task_args, invocation_chain)  #Call the original method
      Rake.application.current_task_chain.pop   #remove the current task (prerequisite) to the "global" chain
    end #invoke_prerequisites
  end #Task
end

task :task1 => :task2
task :task2 => :task3
task :task3 do |tsk|
    puts "Current chain: [%s]->%s" % [Rake.application.current_task_chain.join("->"),tsk.name]
end
#call
if $0 == __FILE__
  Rake.application[:task1].invoke
  Rake.application[:task3].reenable
  Rake.application[:task3].invoke
end
```

Output is

```
Current chain: [task1->task2]->task3
Current chain: []->task3
```

If you need also the task itself, you must also monkey patch `Rake::Task#execute` as in [Is there a way to know the current rake task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363798/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-current-rake-task?rq=3)

No guarantee what happens with parallel processes :)