# Get rake task name in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know, if the app instance is started by `rake`, so I tried out  catching `rake` task name in `initializers`. For example, if I run `rake db:migrate` I want get `db:migrate` or something like this.
I tried this;

```
[7] pry(main)> $0
=> "spring app    | bilet18 | started 3 secs ago | development mode"
[8] pry(main)> ARGV
=> []
[9] pry(main)> Rake.application.top_level_tasks
=> []
```

but everything is empty.

What can I do that? please help.

**UPDATE**

if add in Rakefile line like

```
ENV["RAKE_CURRENT_TASKS"] = Rake.application.top_level_tasks.join(' ')
```

then in future you'll be able to catch it in.
but this solution is not good for me, I need to catch rake task name earlier

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted. It looks like a genuine question to me.

Comment: the downvotes may be from the old post, before it was undeleted and rewritten into an completely different question.

Comment: You are absolutely right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the other answers presented here will work **unless you stop using Spring**, because Spring changes the way rake tasks are called significantly.

When using Spring, the command being run is handed over to the Spring server process using a UNIX socket and unfortunately Spring server reads this socket to get the command and its arguments **after initializing the rails environment**. Thus, during rails initialization, there seems to be no way of getting the command and its arguments (e.g. the rake task name) when using Spring, as Spring itself does not know yet! Even the `after_fork` hook that Spring provides won't help, because it is being also run **after** rails initialization.

A proof can be seen in the Spring source code. It is the [`serve` method](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/lib/spring/application.rb#L136) in which Spring gets the `ARGV` of the command being run from the socket, forks itself and runs the command. The relevant parts of the method are these:

```
def serve(client)
  # ... getting standard input / output streams from the client socket

  # this is where rails initialization occurs
  preload unless preloaded?

  # this is where Spring gets the command name and it's ARGV and environment
  args, env = JSON.load(client.read(client.gets.to_i)).values_at("args", "env")
  command   = Spring.command(args.shift)

  # ...

  # fork and run the command
  pid = fork {
    # ...       
    # run the command
    ARGV.replace(args)
    $0 = command.exec_name
    # ...

    # run the after_fork hook
    invoke_after_fork_callbacks

    command.call
  }

  # ...
end
```

The rails initializers are [run](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/lib/spring/application.rb#L82) in the `preload` method which is run **before** the command name is read from the socket. The `$0` and `ARGV` variables are also set after initialization, in the `fork` block.

So, unless you monkey-patched Spring significantly (replaced the `serve` method with your own, but you'd need to handle working with the socket yourself), **you need to stop calling your rake tasks inside the Spring environment**. If the `rake` command is a binstub in the `RAILS_ROOT/bin/` directory, you need to remove the binstub with `spring binstup --remove rake`.

Only then, I believe, you can use one of the solutions in the other answers.

Comment: Thank you! After cutting out spring it gotta work. You gave full and clear explanation. Great!

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine tasks using `Rake::Task#enhance` to create a variable before invoking the original task, but that seems a bit messy and you'll have to worry about what to do with tasks like `:environment` and `:default`.

I think the easiest way is probably to just extend the `Rake::Task#invoke` method to add a global variable which you could then access in initializers, or from wherever else you want.

Here's a really quick an dirty example which you could do in the `Rakefile`:

```
module RakeTaskName
  def invoke(*args)
    $rake_task_name = name
    super *args
  end
end

Rake::Task.send :prepend, RakeTaskName
```

Then, in an initializer, you can do:

```
if defined? $rake_task_name
  puts "Running from rake task: #{$rake_task_name}"
end
```

**Edit**

[Here's a new rails project](https://github.com/idlefingers/rake-task-name-example) with this code & 1 migration. The output looks like this:

```
Running from rake task: db:migrate
== 20160411150810 CreateFoo: migrating ========================================
-- create_table(:foos)
   -> 0.0010s
== 20160411150810 CreateFoo: migrated (0.0011s) ===============================
```

Comment: Thank you, but for `rake db:migrate` initializers starts before Rakefile, so, i'll get an empty line. Your idea is very similar with that line of code, which I wrote in update part of the question. And both snippets run too late. So it will work with own rake task, except pre-defined.

Comment: @MikeBelyakov Are you sure you're following the example correctly? I generated a new rails app with the code exactly as I have above here, and when you run `rake db:migrate`, you get the puts line followed by the rake task output. See here - https://github.com/idlefingers/rake-task-name-example

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `=> :environment` in your task? E.g.

```
task :sometask => :environment do
    ...
end
```

Otherwise the initializers wont run when you run a rake task

Comment: I need primary it for `rake db:migrate`. Initializers have been run and i can debug it with pry.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to achieve what you want,

1 .Not using `spring`, just run:

```
spring binstub --remove --all
```

and then run your rake task.

2 .Using spring:

create a spring.rb file `config/spring.rb` and use `after_fork`

```
Spring.after_fork do
  # run your code here
  # you have access to ARGV
  binding.pry
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but this idea gives the same result,as i added in update section of the question. As test you can try it with `rake db:migrate` and at this moment. Also, this method will work only with `rake db:migrate`, and not work with `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7492277/2730407) answers your needs. Task name should include also the namespace.

config/initializers/rake.rb

```
module Rake
  class Application
    attr_accessor :current_task
  end
  class Task
    alias :old_execute :execute 
    def execute(args=nil)
      Rake.application.current_task = @name  
      old_execute(args)
    end
  end #class Task
end #module Rake
```

models/something.rb:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
   puts Rake.application.current_task
end
```

lib/tasks/some_task.rake:

```
require 'rake'
namespace :ns do
  task :some_task => :environment do
    Something.all.to_a
  end
end
```

console:

```
rake ns:some_task
ns:some_task
```

also works:

```
bundle exec rake ns:some_task
ns:some_task
```

Comment: Thank you. But this answer clone the idea of my post update. Also, I need to fetch rake task name inside rails app, not inside another rake task. And I can not edit basic rake task- it is built in in rails, `db:migrate` as example.
In this case question is still open.

Comment: I tested it within the app and it works for me. I will edit to explain exactly what I did.

Comment: It is really good method for custom tasks, and I see that it will work.
But it odes not works with built in rake tasks, I try it out with `db:migrate` few minutes ago. May be it will work on other env, I do no know. I use rails 4.2.6, and try rake 10.5 and 11.1.2

Comment: It's true that it doesn't work for rake tasks that do not load the environment as explained by @ved, but it works for db:migrate as well. I just tested it by adding a call to the model `Something` inside a migration. Maybe you should add a code snippet of what it is exactly that you're doing.