# Some modification in Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rakefile

I am new to Ruby programming and Rakefile programming.
I have written a code but the answer is not as expected

```
require './database'

desc "Show number of registered users"
task :report_registered_users do
   arr=Database.new.registered_users
   printf("Month     |   No. Of Users\n")
   printf("----------+----------------\n")
   arr.each do |row|
       printf("%s   |  %s\n",row[0],row[1])
   end
end


desc "Show number of registered devices"
task :report_registered_devices do
   arr=Database.new.registered_devices
   printf("Month     |   No. Of devices\n")
   printf("----------+----------------\n")
   arr.each do |row|
       printf("%s   |  %s\n",row[0],row[1])
   end
end

desc "Show number of unregistered users"
task :report_unregistered_users do
    arr=Database.new.unregistered_users
    printf("Month     |   No. Of Users\n")
    printf("----------+----------------\n")
    arr.each do |row|
        printf("%s   |  %s\n",row[0],row[1])
    end
end

desc "Show number of unregistered devices"
task :report_unregistered_devices do
   arr=Database.new.unregistered_devices
   printf("Month     |   No. Of devices\n")
   printf("----------+----------------\n")
   arr.each do |row|
       printf("%s   |  %s\n",row[0],row[1])
   end
end

desc "Show device per user"
task :report_device_per_user do
   arr=Database.new.device_per_user
   printf("No.of Devices     |   No. Of Users\n")
   printf("----------+----------------\n")
   arr.each do |row|
       printf("%s                  |  %s\n",row[0],row[1])
   end
end
```

The process of running the code is:

```
rake -T
rake report_registered_users
```

When I run the rate -T command the output is like this:

```
rake report_device_per_user         #Show device per user
rake report_registered_devices      #Show number of registered devices
rake report_registered_users        #Show number of registered users
rake report_unregistered_devices    #Show number of unregistered devices
rake report_unregistered_user       #Show number of unregistered user
```

But I want the output to be like this

```
rake report:device_per_user         #Show device per user
rake report:registered_devices      #Show number of registered devices
rake report:registered_users        #Show number of registered users
rake report:unregistered_devices    #Show number of unregistered devices
rake report:unregistered_user       #Show number of unregistered user
```

Notice, the small change in output
report_device_per_user  ----> report:device_per_user

Can someone help me with this solution.....thanks in advance
It might be very basic but i am not able to do it

Comment: Make report a namespace containing the other tasks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106414/rake-default-task-and-namespaces#15213296

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help...I was able to get the result as expected

Answer (score 1):

you need to namespace your tasks

so this ...

```
require './database'

desc "Show number of registered users"
task :report_registered_users do
  ...
end
```

would become this ...

```
require './database'

namespace :report do
  desc "Show number of registered users"
  task :registered_users do
    ...
  end
end
```