# How do I run all rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake, nokogiri

Have just installed whenever gem https://github.com/javan/whenever to run my rake tasks, which are nokogiri / feedzilla dependent scraping tasks.

eg my tasks are called grab_bbc, grab_guardian etc

My question - as I update my site, I keep add more tasks to scheduler.rake.

What should I write in my config/schedule.rb to make all rake tasks run, no matter what they are called?

Would something like this work?

```
    every 12.hours do
        rake:task.each do |task|
            runner task
        end 
    end
```

Am new to Cron, using RoR 4.

Answer (score 12):

```
namespace :sc do
  desc 'All'
  task all: [:create_categories, :create_subcategories]

  desc 'Create categories'
  task create_categories: :environment do
    # your code
  end

  desc 'Create subcategories'
  task create_subcategories: :environment do
    # your code
  end
end
```

in console write $ rake sc:all

Comment: This is the correct answer - both on topic, and succinct

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have a unique namespace with all the tasks in it, like:

```
namespace :scrapers do

  desc "Scraper Number 1" 
  task :scrape_me do
    # Your code here
  end

  desc "Scraper Number 2"
  task :scrape_it do
    # Your code here
  end

end
```

You could then run all tasks of that namespace with a task outside of that namespace:

```
task :run_all_scrapers do
  Rake.application.tasks.each do |task|
    task.invoke if task.name.starts_with?("scrapers:")
  end
end
```

That said, I'm pretty sure that this is not how you should run a set of scrapers. If for any reason the `if` part should return true you might unintenionally run tasks like `rake db:drop`

Either "manually" maintaining `schedule.rb` or a master task seems like a better option to me.

Comment: what is the reason for a namespace? How does it help?

Comment: It is useful to structure tasks into logical groups. `rake db:migrate` runs the `migrate` task from the `db` namespace. In the above example this helps to easily identify which rake tasks to to run.

Comment: You can also use something like `Rake.application.in_namespace(:scrapers){|namespace| namespace.tasks.each(&:invoke)}`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17006916/293280

Answer (score 5):

write separate rake tasks for each scraping tasks. then write a aggregated task to run all those scraping rake tasks.

```
desc "scrape nytimes"
task :scrape_nytimes do
  # scraping method
end

desc "scrape guardian"
task :scrape_guardian do
  # scraping method
end

desc "perform all scraping"
task :scrape do
  Rake::Task[:scrape_nytimes].execute 
  Rake::Task[:scrape_guardian].execute 
end
```

then call the rake task as

```
rake scrape
```

Comment: Thanks Khan. How do I run those tasks automatically every X hours, or every time I view the development site, so that my development site updates without my writing "rake scrape" manually in  Terminal?

Comment: @Jonathan_W, you can simply add a cron job to schedule this rake task to run every x hour hour. if you want to scrape when loading dev site then my suggestion is to write the scraping task as a seperate function and call this function from your web apps controller. also call the same function from rake task.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregated task can be concise:

```
namespace :scrape do
  desc "scrape nytimes"
  task :nytimes do
    # scraping method
  end

  desc "scrape guardian"
  task :guardian do
    # scraping method
  end
end

desc "perform all scraping"
task scrape: ['scrape:nytimes', 'scrape:guardian']
```

Namespaces are also a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `namespace` and `in_namespace` to run all tasks dynamically.

I prefer this method because it keeps things clean and precludes you from having to remember to update your "parent" task if any of our namespace tasks change.

*Note, the example was borrowed from [Dmitry Shvetsov's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37594031/293280).*

```rb
namespace :scrape do
  desc "scrape nytimes"
  task :nytimes do
    # scraping method
  end

  desc "scrape guardian"
  task :guardian do
    # scraping method
  end
end

desc "perform all scraping"
task :scrape do
  Rake.application.in_namespace( :scrape ){ |namespace| namespace.tasks.each( &:invoke ) }
end
```