# Run all rake tasks inside a shared namespace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to run a list of rake task within a shared `:namespace` following this post: [How do I run all rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580649/how-do-i-run-all-rake-tasks).

But its not working.

**Recommendation per post**

```
desc "perform all scraping"
task :scrape do
  Rake::Task[:scrape_nytimes].execute 
  Rake::Task[:scrape_guardian].execute 
end
```

The difference in my case is that all rake tasks are in a namespace.

**Rake tasks**

```
namespace :get_ready do
  task check_weather: :environment do
    p 1
  end
  task make_lunch: :environment do
    p 2
  end
  task start_car: :environment do
    p 3
  end
end
```

Attempting to create a rake task that runs all rake tasks as below.

```
desc "Run all tasks"
task run_all: :environment do
  Rake::Task[:check_weather].execute 
  Rake::Task[:make_lunch].execute    
  Rake::Task[:start_car].execute       
end
```

And then running with `rake run_all` or `rake get_ready`. The below variations I tried also didn't work.

- `Rake::Task[run_all:check_weather].execute`
- `Rake::Task[:run_all, :check_weather].execute`

Does anyone have experience running a batch of rake tasks in a shared namespace and knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
desc "Run all tasks"
task run_all: :environment do
  Rake::Task['get_ready:check_weather'].execute 
  Rake::Task['get_ready:make_lunch'].execute    
  Rake::Task['get_ready:start_car'].execute       
end
```

The namespace is `get_ready` and `check_weather`, `make_lunch`, `start_car` are task in that namespace.

More elegant solution is:

```
desc "Run all tasks"
task run_all_elegantly: [:environment, 'get_ready:check_weather', 'get_ready:make_lunch', 'get_ready:start_car']
```

Answer (score 0):

Every noticed the output of `rails -T` or in your case `rails -T get_ready` ?
It shows every command, and the description as comment, so you could pipe the output and execute it with bash:

```
(rails -T deploy) | /bin/bash
```

So there is no need to make an extra task if you want to execute all tasks.