# Call simple rake task from parent task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I want to create very simple rake task. From one main task I want to call all sub tasks. I tried this code:

```
namespace :my_namespace do

  task create_all_users: :environment do
    puts "Creating all users"

    create_admin
    create_user

  end

  task create_admin: :environment do
    puts "Creating admin user"
    ######
  end

  task create_user: :environment do
    puts "Creating user"
    ######
  end

end
```

But I get error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `create_admin' for main:Object
```

What is the proper way to call the tasks?

Answer (score 1):

place the default task outside the namespace as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579280/2245329). or use actual methods as suggested by @tthomas7 [referred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290119/2245329)

with *option 1* your code will looks like:

```
namespace :my_namespace do

  task create_admin: :environment do
    puts "Creating admin user"
    ######
  end

  task create_user: :environment do
    puts "Creating user"
    ######
  end

end

task create_all_users: :environment do
  puts "Creating all users"

  Rake::Task["my_namespace:create_admin"].invoke
  Rake::Task["my_namespace:create_user"].invoke

end
```